# Counted and Terminated String in Java

Tags: java

> Two methods of implementing a string. A counted string explicitly
>   records its length. The terminated string’s length is determined by an
>   end-of-string mark.

Can anyone give an example of counted string and a terminated string in java.

Comment: Where did you get that from? Why do you want to know that? Smells like homework.

Comment: http://www.cs.williams.edu/javastructures/Book_files/JavaStructures.pdf

Comment: I mean, Java can't exactly have a terminated string in the same way that C can, because all array lengths are known at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CountedString {
   char[] string;
   int length;

   int getLength() {
     return length;
   }
}


TerminatedString {
   char[] string;
   final static char TERMINATOR = '$';
   int getLength() {
     for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (string[i] == TERMINATOR) return i;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look in to the [String.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) will find that the length of String is being calculated by counter which traverse through string's characters .

Please refer`String.java` for more information.  You should look in to this class to see implementation of `length()`  method.